# Replace cell values in one file with another value from another file

Tags: sed, awk

So I have two files:

**file1**:

> header1
>   header2
>   123 0.0000
>   abc def ghi
>   jkl mno pqr
>   234 0.0000
>   cab fde igh
>   ljk omn rpq
>   345 0.0000
>   bca efd hig
>   klj nom qrp
>   .
>   .
>   .

**file2**:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   .
>   .
>   .

The output that I want is:

> header1
>   header2
>   1 0.0000
>   abc def ghi
>   jkl mno pqr
>   2 0.0000
>   cab fde igh
>   ljk omn rpq
>   3 0.0000
>   bca efd hig
>   klj nom qrp
>   .
>   .
>   .

Basically I want to change the values in front of /0.0000/ pattern in file1 with the values from file2. Kindly do let me know if there is any other efficient way to do it in Awk/Sed.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work. When the value `0.0000` seen in field 2 in `file1`, use [getline](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_25.html#SEC28) to read the next record from `file2` into the variable `var` and replace field 1 with `var`.

```
awk '$2 == "0.0000"{getline var <"file2";$1=var};{print}' file1
```

Comment: @user3006147, added some explanation

Comment: It works for the examples, but when I applied it to my file I didn't work properly. Could you please explain it what the meaning of your script so I cant get better understanding?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3006147, please add some sample data to the question for the case where the solution does not work

Comment: So I modified your script into " awk '/0.0000/{getline var < "file2";$1=var};{print}' file1 " to get the results that I want. As I just want to change the value in front of 0.0000. And it works like a charm. If you don't mind could you explain your script? Many Thanks.

Comment: @user3006147, you may want to use the modified version of my script above. I have tried to add some explanation but you need to know the basics of `awk` first. All the best and glad to be of help!